# Get Product with the filter using OR operator

Tags: magento

In Magento,
I want to get the product with `name` attribute is ***`Product 1`*** **OR** ***`Product 2`***

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('name','Product 1')
    ->setPageSize(1)
    ->load()
    ->getFirstItem();
//OR 
if( !$product->getId() )
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('name','Product 2')
        ->setPageSize(1)
        ->load()
        ->getFirstItem();
}
```

How can I just using one statement to do?